# Differentiate between users at database level in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In an application based on mongodb, I want to differentiate between users (normal users and administrator) vs manager (customized user for the app) at database level (means there is only one button for login irrespective of the type of users) so that while searching the manager in a collection (which has all the users whether normal users, administrators, managers) can be searched.

I could get the gist that using role of mongodb we can do it. But not getting in a proper way whether we really can do via this way or there is any other method.

Any pointers please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not a really clear question with an **example** as it should be but you seem to asking about "restricting" entries in documents or possibly collection documents themselves to certain users. For the first case, look at [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) as a new feature of MongoDB 2.6 and upwards. In the second case, simply add an "ACL" type field to your documents to determine who can access them

Comment: Are you asking about modelling users and their roles in database schema, or about having database logins (the `username` in `mongodb://username:password@.../`) with different permissions (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authorization/)?

Comment: @Messa I certainly hope the former is the case because the latter would be "off-topic" as database administration is not a "programming topic" which is what this site is specifically for. There are other sites in the stackexchange network where you can talk "DBA" stuff if that is what you ( or the OP ) want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a user type field in the user collection (regular, admin etc.)

Alternatively, if users can belong to multiple roles I would add a roles collection to specify the roles per user.

Answer (score 0):

**In terms of application**

In your users collection have a field called role.

Have a separate roles collection where for each role, you can specify the privileges.

So when the user logs in, refer the user role and process accordingly.

**In terms of DB**

In your mongodb setup the different roles first like below

```
db.runCommand({ 
  createRole: "manager",
  privileges: [
    { resource: { db: "users", collection: "usersCollection" }, actions: [ "update", "insert", "remove" ] },
    { resource: { db: "", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find" ] }
  ],
  roles: [
    { role: "read", db: "admin" }
  ],
  writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 } // you can avoid if not a pro
})

// mention the resources and actions inside privileges
```

add this role to the user when creating the users.

So when the user logs in, only allowed actions can be performed by him

For more details refer [MongoDocs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/createRole/#dbcmd.createRole)